# Array transformation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-transform

I want to take an array of objects so I can map them into a table given a unique value in the objects.
Data looks as follow:

```
const data = [{
    customer: 1,
    location: home,
    orderQty: 3},
    {
    customer: 2,
    location: home,
    orderQty: 2},
    {
    customer: 1,
    location: work,
    orderQty: 3},
    {
    customer: 3,
    location: apartment,
    orderQty: 2}]
```

I need something like the output below:

```
const dataByLocation = [{
    location: home,
    list: [{ customer: 1,
          orderQty: 3},
         { customer: 2, 
           orderQty: 2}]
          },{
    location: work,
    list: [{ customer: 1,
         orderQty: 3}]
         },{
    location: apartment,
    list: [{ customer: 3,
         orderQty: 2}]
}]
```

I've tried a few map methods but just cannot find solution

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's always a good idea to show what attempts you've made and research you've done in the question as code and links, rather than just "I've tried a few things". Also, when asking to go from input to output, it's a good idea to describe what the steps are to get the data from the input to the output. Finally, formatting can be important. Currently, it's quite hard to tell where objects start and end in the arrays because of the odd use of indentation.

Comment: No problem it is my first time on here just starting out. Apologies